# Why webpack bundle analyzer show lodash bundled more than once?

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, lodash, tree-shaking

We use [webpack-bundle-analyzer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer) to visualize what is bundled in our application and optimize it.

It appears `lodash` is imported, among many other `lodash.*` package (those package are just small part of lodash), you can visualize lodash in red in the following screenshot:

[image]

In our [`package.json`](https://github.com/pass-culture/pass-culture-app-native/blob/master/package.json), we only have installed `lodash.*` modules, and in our sources we only import those module, we never `import 'lodash'` directly.

This is the result of `npm ls lodash`:

```rb
$ npm ls lodash
PassCulture@1.199.0 /home/dka/workspace/github.com/pass-culture/pass-culture-app-native
├─┬ @lingui/cli@3.13.2
│ └─┬ inquirer@7.3.3
│   └── lodash@4.17.21 deduped
├─┬ @react-native-community/eslint-config@3.0.1
│ └─┬ eslint-plugin-flowtype@2.50.3
│   └── lodash@4.17.21 deduped
├─┬ @sentry/react-native@4.1.2
│ └─┬ @sentry/wizard@1.2.17
│   ├─┬ inquirer@6.5.2
│   │ └── lodash@4.17.21 deduped
│   └── lodash@4.17.21 deduped
├─┬ @storybook/addon-a11y@6.5.3
│ ├─┬ @storybook/api@6.5.3
│ │ └── lodash@4.17.21 deduped
│ ├─┬ @storybook/csf@0.0.2--canary.4566f4d.1
│ │ └── lodash@4.17.21 deduped
│ └── lodash@4.17.21
├─┬ @storybook/addon-actions@6.5.3
│ ├── lodash@4.17.21 deduped
│ └─┬ telejson@6.0.8
│   └── lodash@4.17.21 deduped
├─┬ @storybook/addon-essentials@6.5.3
│ ├─┬ @storybook/addon-controls@6.5.3
│ │ └── lodash@4.17.21 deduped
│ └─┬ @storybook/addon-docs@6.5.3
│   ├─┬ @storybook/mdx1-csf@0.0.1-canary.1.867dcd5.0 invalid: "canary" from node_modules/@storybook/addon-docs
│   │ └── lodash@4.17.21 deduped
│   ├─┬ @storybook/preview-web@6.5.3
│   │ └── lodash@4.17.21 deduped
│   ├─┬ @storybook/source-loader@6.5.3
│   │ └── lodash@4.17.21 deduped
│   └── lodash@4.17.21 deduped
├─┬ @storybook/addon-interactions@6.5.9
│ ├─┬ @storybook/api@6.5.9
│ │ └── lodash@4.17.21 deduped
│ └─┬ @storybook/instrumenter@6.5.9
│   └─┬ @storybook/addons@6.5.9
│     └─┬ @storybook/api@6.5.9
│       └── lodash@4.17.21 deduped
├─┬ @storybook/react@6.5.3
│ ├─┬ @storybook/core@6.5.3
│ │ ├─┬ @storybook/core-client@6.5.3
│ │ │ ├─┬ @storybook/client-api@6.5.3
│ │ │ │ └── lodash@4.17.21 deduped
│ │ │ └── lodash@4.17.21 deduped
│ │ └─┬ @storybook/core-server@6.5.3
│ │   ├─┬ @storybook/core-client@6.5.3
│ │   │ └── lodash@4.17.21 deduped
│ │   └── lodash@4.17.21 deduped
│ ├─┬ @storybook/docs-tools@6.5.3
│ │ └── lodash@4.17.21 deduped
│ ├─┬ @storybook/store@6.5.3
│ │ └── lodash@4.17.21 deduped
│ ├─┬ babel-plugin-react-docgen@4.2.1
│ │ └── lodash@4.17.21 deduped
│ └── lodash@4.17.21 deduped
├─┬ @testing-library/jest-dom@5.16.2
│ └── lodash@4.17.21 deduped
├─┬ @welldone-software/why-did-you-render@6.2.3
│ └── lodash@4.17.21 deduped
├─┬ appcenter-cli@2.10.10
│ ├─┬ inquirer@8.2.0
│ │ └── lodash@4.17.21 deduped
│ └── lodash@4.17.21 deduped
├─┬ babel-core@6.26.3
│ ├─┬ babel-generator@6.26.1
│ │ └── lodash@4.17.21 deduped
│ ├─┬ babel-register@6.26.0
│ │ └── lodash@4.17.21 deduped
│ ├─┬ babel-template@6.26.0
│ │ └── lodash@4.17.21 deduped
│ ├─┬ babel-traverse@6.26.0
│ │ └── lodash@4.17.21 deduped
│ ├─┬ babel-types@6.26.0
│ │ └── lodash@4.17.21 deduped
│ └── lodash@4.17.21 deduped
├─┬ babel-plugin-styled-components@2.0.7
│ └── lodash@4.17.21 deduped
├─┬ flipper-plugin-react-query-native-devtools@3.0.0
│ └── lodash@4.17.21 deduped
├─┬ html-webpack-plugin@4.5.2
│ ├── lodash@4.17.21 deduped
│ └─┬ pretty-error@2.1.2
│   ├── lodash@4.17.21 deduped
│   └─┬ renderkid@2.0.7
│     └── lodash@4.17.21 deduped
├─┬ jest@26.6.3
│ └─┬ @jest/core@26.6.3
│   └─┬ jest-config@26.6.3
│     └─┬ jest-environment-jsdom@26.6.2
│       └─┬ jsdom@16.7.0
│         ├─┬ data-urls@2.0.0
│         │ └─┬ whatwg-url@8.7.0
│         │   └── lodash@4.17.21 deduped
│         └─┬ whatwg-url@8.7.0
│           └── lodash@4.17.21 deduped
├─┬ optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin@5.0.8
│ └─┬ last-call-webpack-plugin@3.0.0
│   └── lodash@4.17.21 deduped
├─┬ react-native-calendars@1.1284.0
│ └── lodash@4.17.21 deduped
├─┬ react-native@0.68.2
│ ├─┬ @react-native-community/cli-platform-android@7.0.1
│ │ ├─┬ @react-native-community/cli-tools@7.0.1
│ │ │ └── lodash@4.17.21 deduped
│ │ └── lodash@4.17.21 deduped
│ ├─┬ @react-native-community/cli-platform-ios@7.0.1
│ │ ├─┬ @react-native-community/cli-tools@7.0.1
│ │ │ └── lodash@4.17.21 deduped
│ │ └── lodash@4.17.21 deduped
│ └─┬ @react-native-community/cli@7.0.3
│   ├─┬ @react-native-community/cli-hermes@6.3.0
│   │ └─┬ @react-native-community/cli-platform-android@6.3.0
│   │   └── lodash@4.17.21 deduped
│   ├─┬ @react-native-community/cli-tools@6.2.0
│   │ └── lodash@4.17.21 deduped
│   └── lodash@4.17.21 deduped
├─┬ styled-components@5.3.3
│ └─┬ babel-plugin-styled-components@2.0.2
│   └── lodash@4.17.21 deduped
├─┬ ts-jest@26.5.6
│ └── lodash@4.17.21 deduped
├─┬ webpack-bundle-analyzer@4.5.0
│ └── lodash@4.17.21 deduped
├─┬ webpack-dev-server@3.11.3
│ ├─┬ http-proxy-middleware@0.19.1
│ │ └── lodash@4.17.21 deduped
│ └─┬ portfinder@1.0.28
│   └─┬ async@2.6.4
│     └── lodash@4.17.21 deduped
├─┬ webpack-manifest-plugin@2.2.0
│ └── lodash@4.17.21 deduped
└─┬ workbox-webpack-plugin@6.4.2
  └─┬ workbox-build@6.4.2
    └── lodash@4.17.21 deduped
```

As you can see, all the modules are devDependencies except one which is `@sentry/react-native` (our webapp is also a react-native app), I doubt this is the reason why lodash get bundled, but I have raised an issue [sentry-wizard/issues/182](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-wizard/issues/182) and [sentry-react-native/issues/2409](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-react-native/issues/2409).

Also, the web just bundle in dev environment, but there is no `node_modules` folder distributed in the production build, this is how webpack work, so this whole `lodash` is a mystery.

Why does the whole `lodash` get also imported and how can I improve my bundle?

Answer (score -1):

The other packages in your image are in fact not the `lodash` package, but other individual packaged lodash functions.

See: https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.debounce

If you haven't added them to your package.json, then it is likely that your dependencies did and they are bundled alongside `lodash`.

I personally would recommend not to optimize these imports, since they are quite small in comparison, but attempt to use tree-shakeable lodash imports, which would help much more.

i.e.

Do not

```js
import {keyBy} from 'lodash' // Bundled as lodash.js. Though there are babel plugins that would convert this to imports below.
```

Do

```js
import keyBy from 'lodash/keyBy' // Bundled as keyBy.js. One of the small squares next to lodash.js
```

Doing so would eliminate bundling the complete lodash.js, which your application very likely doesn't completely utilize.